# How to create a static storage for live data that doesn't crash in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, MAIN and Static Data.
MAIN is constantly being updated with data pretty much every second.
I want to have a sheet with the exact same data and format as MAIN but the data is stored as static, ie no formulas.

I created the following macro:

```
Sub macro_timer()
'Tells Excel when to next run the macro.
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CopyMain"

End Sub

Public Sub CopyMain()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Worksheets("Static Data").Cells.ClearContents
    With Worksheets("Static Data")
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy .Range("A1")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    End With
    Call macro_timer
End Sub
```

I use Worksheets(i) since MAIN is the first sheet in the workbook, I copy the entire table in MAIN and then place it into the Static Data sheet with only the values, no formulas. So, this code achieves the goal of turning the live formulaic data into static, its just the frequency of updates of MAIN that this function struggles with.

This only works when MAIN is not being updated at such a high rate. Is there a way to create a more robust solution?

Currently, I copy the entire MAIN sheet into Static Data, is there a way to only change the values in Static Data that have changed in MAIN in the last second in order to help with speed and crash prevention?

Comment: How exactly is MAIN being updated? Perhaps the `Worksheet_Change` event would be applicable, a guess.

Comment: API calls every second, not in every cell but multiple